# Remove old role once new one purchased

Tags: ubercart

Someone created a module for this called `uc_clear` roles so you can stop what's happening to me now which is when a new role is purchased it is just added to the old one.
But this module is only for Drupal 6 and I am using 7.

Logintoboggan preauthorize role if the user neglects to verify it and then buys a role, the new role will replace it but if verified and user makes purchase for upgrade they end up with both free membership status as well as paid. I don't yet know how to write php or create a module but, could the RULES module do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Rules to manage roles.

Rules need Event to react on, Condition to evaluate for truth, Action to perform.

Event: It is hard to tell from from your post what would be your Event. I don't use Ubercart, but I assume it provides some Rules Events like Commerce, e.g. 'After adding a product to the cart,' 'On checkout coompletion,' and so on. There's also 'Before saving a user account,' 'After saving a user account' and so on.

Condition: "User has role(s)"

Action: "Add user role", "Remove user role"

Very simple actually.

[ Note also that the current version of Rules (2.8) is BROKEN with Commerce 2 ... not sure if the problem also exists with Ubercart ... users of Commerce have to downgrade Rules to 2.7 ]

Comment: in ubercart the event would be "Customer completes checkout" to occur after final payment is received, etc

Comment: Thanks , that sounds simple enough. I am already using rules for redirect on log out so am sure can give it a go.